# Trying to remove disable attr on an html button tag when the input value is > 0 && value !== undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Struggling to remove the disable attr. on a button.

Javascript is not reading anything I put into the input field

I have tried a lot of things...lol

// Here is my button in Html

```
<button id="rollDice" class="mainBtns btn-roll" disabled>
<i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>

<input class="finalScore" type="text" placeholder="Winning Score">

// My JavaScript to see if value is true / false

var enableRoll = document.querySelector('.finalScore').value;

    if (enableRoll > 0 && enableRoll !==  undefined) {
        document.getElementById('rollDice').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
```

When I enter a value into the Html Page, it isnt registered.

When I wrap Number() around enableRoll i get NaN --

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Nit: `"type"` is not a valid `type`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Oops, thanks! but that was a recently when i tried using type="number"
 and doesn't solve it

Comment: You should check for undefined before the `> 0` check. Then inside the if, do a `console.log('asd')` and see if it ever gets ther. Also, you don't have a change listener on the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of enabling it when the text changes. Note use of parseInt

```js
const enableRoll = () => parseInt(document.querySelector('.finalScore').value);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // NOTE: Change occurs when loses focus
  document.querySelector('.finalScore').addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (enableRoll() > 0) {
      console.log('enabling button');
      document.getElementById('rollDice').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<button id="rollDice" class="mainBtns btn-roll" disabled>
<i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>

<input class="finalScore" type="type" placeholder="Winning Score">
```

Comment: You're a legend, it works!! Thank you very much. I don't have time right now to dissect the code but I will work on understanding it tomorrow.

I didn't think the solution would require so much code. Thanks again!!

Comment: parseInt only turns a 'number string' into a integer of the specified radix. So '23' into 23. So if you want to make pretty sure users don't enter 'string' ( letters) you should use a `type='number'` input and/or more validation. Also, for parseInt you should specify a radix ( 10 in 99% of cases )

Comment: Thanks Bibberty, I dont have enough rep lol. I will when I am worthy.

&& Thanks Mihai, i will do that!

Answer (score 0):

You should use onkeyup if you want your button to be enabled while user types in the input field.

I suggest you use a `number` input so you are pretty sure only numbers can be entered. That might not be enough and if you have a 'sensible' application, you should consider adding more validation for this. Plus some other validations regarding not starting with 0 and so on.

I also suggest you use `const` and `let` when declaring variables. There is a ton of documentation on the web regarding this.

And ofc use an else statement if the user deletes all the input content/value.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.finalScore');
const button = document.getElementById('rollDice');

input.onkeyup = function(e) {
  const enableRoll = parseInt(e.target.value,10)
  console.log(enableRoll)
  if (typeof enableRoll !== undefined && enableRoll > 0) {
    button.removeAttribute('disabled')
  } else {
    button.setAttribute('disabled','disabled')
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="rollDice" class="mainBtns btn-roll" disabled>
<i class="ion-ios-loop"></i>Roll dice</button>

<input class="finalScore" type="text" placeholder="Winning Score" >
```

P.S. Word of advice. When comparing number values do not use `if (value)` to check if the value exists. Compare it with undefined or/and null. Because if the value is 0, the if will return false. Just putting this out there :)

Comment: I look into this solution too but a look a little more advanced than where Im at currently. Thanks for you time!

Comment: @CraigMazerall it's not that advanced. And i explained in the answer almost all that you need to know. If my answer, or another answer worked for you, please rate them as accepted ( do not need a certain reputation to do that , it's a ' green tick ' )

Comment: ok I ticked it. Its says 'Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
document.getElementById('rollDice').disabled = false
```

There is no need ot validate `enableRoll !==  undefined`, cause `undefined > 0` returns false

For the NaN part, any NaN will return `NaN > 0` false

Comment: You should include a working snippet in your answer. If you would've done that, you would've noticed that just `document.getElementById('rollDice').disabled = false` without an onchage/onkeyup function won't work, because on page load the value is  an empty string.